# Warning: require_once(./mailer/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, require-once, include-once

#### Tree:

```
--myproject
----mailer
-------class.phpmailer.php
----test
-------index.php
----site.php
----class.php
----db.php
----index.php
```

#### index.php: (both)

```
<?php 
require_once '../site.php';
?>
```

#### site.php:

```
<?php
require_once "class.php";
?>
```

#### class.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
require_once('./mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
?>
```

---

When I visit test it shows:

> Warning: require_once(./mailer/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\myproject\class.php
>   on line 3
>
> ---
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './mailer/class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\myproject\class.php on line 3

---

I also tried `include_once` but same error!

Comment: First of all, why are you doing `require_once '../site.php';` if both site.php and index.php are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the

```
require_once('./mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

From inside index.php, so the file is two levels above.

Change

```
require_once('./mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

to

```
require_once('../mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

**UPDATE**

Just realized you need both index.php files working. It's not the prettiest solution, but you can do it like this:

**/test/index.php**

```
<?php

$nested = true;
require_once '../site.php';

?>
```

**/index.php**

```
<?php 

$nested = false;
require_once 'site.php';

?>
```

This new "nested" variable will determine if the file is inside a directory or on the base.

Edit your **class.php** to look like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

if ($nested == true)
require_once('../mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

elseif ($nested == false)
require_once('./mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

?>
```

This should fix the problem in both files.

Comment: @tusa check my update, this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and include the full path.

For example, on both `index.php` files you can do:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site.php');
```

And on `site.php`

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class.php');
```

And on `class.php`

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

The reason why? Because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will dynamically return the full file path on the server to the document root. This is like saying (assuming your document root is `/www/username/public_html`):

```
require_once('/www/username/public_html/db.php');
```

Which will always be the same - until you change to a new directory location or server. When that happens, instead of re-writing every `require_once()`, because you have used `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, PHP will do the work for you.

Using a relative path can be confusing compared to a absolute path as it is relative to current location.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer this question.

On file index.php under folder test you can use code as follow:

```
<?php 
require_once '../site.php';
?>
```

On site.php you can use code as follow:

```
<?php
require_once "class.php";
?>
```

On class.php you can add code as follow:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
?>
```

On file index.php on root of folder myproject you can use code as follow:

```
<?php 
require_once 'site.php';
?>
```

I hope this trick can help up you.